# Extract multi-word phrases with surrounding context

Tags: python-3.x, csv, nlp

I have written some code which looks for the three words before and after certain key words which are contained in multiple lists which are subsequently joined into a larger list (list "words" in the code). It writes the output to a .csv file and works fine for single words but not phrases. To illustrate there are a series of lists containing words such as

```py
approx = ["approximately"]
could = ["could"]
```

and phrases such as

```py
can_be = ["can be"]
shouldbeso = ["should be so"]
```

These are concatenated into one larger list which we're calling "words".  The program can find all 3 words to the left  and to the right of "approximately", "could" or similar words, but misses out completely the phrases.

Is there a way to modify the code to detect the three words before and after specific phrases?  My code is as follows.

```py
path = 'D:/Testing'

context_d = {}
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(filename)
        file = f.read()
       # txt = file.lower()
        txt = file.split()
        txt = [item.replace('May', '') for item in txt]  # locate and replace all months of May before lowering
        # txt = list([[word.lower() for word in line.split()] for line in txt])
        txt = (list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), txt)))
        for j in range(len(txt)):
          if (j + 3) < len(txt):
           if txt[j] in words:
            if txt[j] in context_d:
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j - 3):j]
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 3)]
            else:
             context_d[txt[j]] = txt[(j - 3):j]
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 3)]
```

Comment: Can you post an input example of the two different scenario you re talking about ? It will make easier for us to understand.

Comment: I've added some more explanatory text in how the data for the words and phrases to be identified is created.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with uno.txt:

```
gallina sparviero Mulo tonno  ASINO maiale foca cavallo boa struzzo May May
peperone cipolla aglio cavolo oca gallo bue pippo mucca
```

due.txt:

```
pizza pasta tagliolini acciughe peperone burro oca cavolo baccala
pollo pizza pasta gamberi peperone uva cipolla grano
pesce gatto mulo ASINO verdura broccoli pippo 'hamburger formaggio' panna
```

tre.txt:

```
pinguino leone mummia 'oca gallo' levriero bassotto pecora capra
```

and prova.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Dec 28 16:11:33 2020

@author: Pietro
"""

import glob
import os
import shlex


path = './'

words = ['pippo' ,'papera', 'asino', 'ciuchino' , 'peperone' ,'oca gallo' , 'hamburger formaggio']


print('\n\n keywords to search for : ',words,'\n\n')

context_d = {}
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(filename)
        file = f.read()
#        print('\nprinting file :  \n\n'+file)
       # txt = file.lower()
#        print('++++++++hhhhhhhh++++++\n\n',file)
#        txt = file.split()
        txt = shlex.split(file)
#        print('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n\n',txt)
        txt = [item.replace('May', '') for item in txt]  # locate and replace all months of May before lowering
       #txt = list([[word.lower() for word in line.split()] for line in txt])
        txt = (list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), txt)))
        print('\n\n printing txt : \n\n',txt,'\n\n')
        for j in range(len(txt)):
#          if (j + 3) < len(txt):
           if txt[j] in words:
            if txt[j] in context_d:
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j - 3):j]
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 4)]
            else:
             context_d[txt[j]] = txt[(j - 3):j]
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 4)]

#    print('\n\n printing context_d : \n\n ', context_d,'\n\n')
    

for i in context_d:
    context_d[i] = list(set(context_d[i]))
    
for i in context_d:
    print(i , context_d[i],'\n\n')
```

When run I got:

```
 keywords to search for :  ['pippo', 'papera', 'asino', 'ciuchino', 'peperone', 'oca gallo', 'hamburger formaggio'] 


asino ['cavallo', 'pesce', 'tonno', 'foca', 'sparviero', 'broccoli', 'maiale', 'verdura', 'mulo', 'gatto', 'pippo'] 


peperone ['', 'struzzo', 'uva', 'burro', 'grano', 'acciughe', 'pizza', 'cipolla', 'gamberi', 'cavolo', 'tagliolini', 'pasta', 'oca', 'aglio'] 


pippo ['panna', 'hamburger formaggio', 'bue', 'mucca', 'broccoli', 'gallo', 'verdura', 'asino', 'oca'] 


oca gallo ['pecora', 'pinguino', 'leone', 'mummia', 'bassotto', 'levriero'] 


hamburger formaggio ['broccoli', 'verdura', 'panna', 'pippo']
```

Is this the right behavior?

If so I needed to change:

```
 if txt[j] in context_d:
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j - 3):j]
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 3)]
            else:
             context_d[txt[j]] = txt[(j - 3):j]
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 3)]
```

with

```
 if txt[j] in context_d:
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j - 3):j]
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 4)]
            else:
             context_d[txt[j]] = txt[(j - 3):j]
             context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 4)]
```

and:

```
txt = file.split()
```

with

```
txt = shlex.split(file)
```

Let me know if it is right (sure there would be better faster more pythonic ways).

Comment: Hi pippo1980, yes the behaviour for words looks correct, it produces a similar output to what I get in my .csv file.

Comment: @JFDA_64    Why :     if (j + 3) < len(txt): if I remove that seems to work as well. Isn't it ?

Comment: if (j + 3) < len(txt): is there to make sure there is no error generated by the word not having any other words within three words of the end of the text file.

Comment: to me worked as well removing it and using a word in words as second last element of txt file

Comment: You're quite right it does work for single words with that line removed. Still doesn't detect the use of 2-4 words which form a phrase.

Comment: I’ll try tomorrow. Watching ATeam the movie right now. Was thinking about putting underscore in between phrases words but then my python knowledge wasn’t enough to file.split() it right. My regex is null. I’ll try with shlex.split(). Wondering how to parse a unique string file to get the phrases out of it but I guess this would be another question

Comment: I've looked at regex as well, but even though it will find a phrase in a string, I need to be able to grab three words either side of the string which is becoming a real issue.

Comment: @JFDA_64 done not sure if it's right let me know

Comment: pippo1980, sorry for the delayed response but I've been busy with other matters over the last few weeks.  On running your solution it generates the error.  "raise ValueError("No closing quotation") ValueError: No closing quotation"  On further investigation this seems to be a problem with the shlex function itself. Also, what is the purpose of the line of code, newfile = file.replace(phrases[k], ('\'' + phrases[k] + '\'')), not sure exactly what it does.

Comment: to me it works, but I am using my input files as posted

Comment: newfile = file.replace(phrases[k], ('\'' + phrases[k] + '\'')) not sure but I think it adds a ' to bot ends of phrases[k] that should be a string,  list object doesnt have attribute replace

Comment: The shlex command is still generating the error I wrote about a couple of weeks ago.  I suspect the reason is the extensive use of quotation marks and punctuation, but can't be exactly sure.  I will remove those by cleaning the text files more extensively as the other contributor suggested and then try running it again.

Answer (score 0):

Without example texts to test with, it's hard to know what to expect - can we assume whitespace is regularized and punctuation is always adjacent to the preceding word, and separated from the following word by whitespace, for example?  But this should at least get you started with a regex solution.

```py
import re

words = set(approx + could)         # add more
phrases = set(can_be + shouldbeso)  # add more

expr = r'((?:\S+\s+){0,3}(?:%s)[.,:;?!]*(?:\s+\S+){0,3})' % '|'.join(words.union(phrases))
regex = re.compile(expr, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    #  if filename.endswith('.txt'): -- useless, we already globbed for only files with that extension
    # prefer a with statement
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.replace('May', '')
            m = regex.findall(line)
            if m:
                print(m)
```

This has the obvious drawback that a line which matches multiple of your search phrases with less than six words separating them will have less context around each match.  For example, the input line

```
the diameter can be no longer than approximately 3in
```

will report "the diameter can be no longer than" as the first match, and just "approximtely 3in" as the second, because the first already "ate" the words after it; and

```
the diameter can be approximately 3in
```

will simply find "can be" and completely consume "approximately" as part of the captured surrounding context.

If that's a problem, perhaps loop over a set of regexes for each line, and extract any matches from each.

```
regexes = [re.compile(r'((?:\S+\s+){0,3}(?:%s)[.,:;?!]*(?:\s+\S+){0,3})' % phrase, flags=re.IGNORECASE) for phrase in words.union(phrases)]

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.replace('May', '')
            for regex in regexes:
                m = regex.findall(line)
                if m:
                    print(m)
```

You'll notice the optional group `[.,:;?!]*` which allows for unlimited punctuation immediately after the matched words. Perhaps you would like to exclude this, or - for more real-world text examples - perhaps extend it to also allow quoting, dashes (like in the embedded adverbial earlier in this sentence), parentheses (like here), etc.

Customarily, you would preprocess your input to discard or normalize punctuation, as well as perhaps capitalization. Using *only* regular expressions will be painful for any real-world inputs.

Comment: I've ran your solution and it seems to work better for the phrases than it does for individual words (ironic really)  Given that, and since I already have a version which works on single words, I'm going to use this regex version for processing the phrases alone and see how that works.

Comment: "Better" how? Too late now really to finally update your question with some real examples, but maybe ask a new question with proper details if you still need help.

Comment: The regex engine will always prefer the longest-leftmost match. If your words and phrases have overlaps (like match both "can" and "can be") then the first solution will fail for some of them some of the time, but the second should still work eminently.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to improve first answer, don't need to highlight phrases into input file (won't work if any single quote is in present in input file):

Tried with uno.txt:

```
gallina sparviero Mulo tonno  ASINO maiale foca cavallo boa struzzo May May
peperone cipolla aglio cavolo oca gallo bue pippo mucca
```

due.txt:

```
pizza pasta tagliolini acciughe peperone burro oca cavolo baccala
pollo pizza pasta gamberi peperone uva cipolla grano
pesce gatto mulo ASINO verdura broccoli pippo hamburger formaggio panna
```

tre.txt:

```
pinguino leone mummia oca gallo levriero bassotto pecora capra
```

and prova.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Dec 28 16:11:33 2020

@author: Pietro
"""

import glob

import os

import shlex

path = './'

words = ['pippo' ,'papera', 'asino', 'ciuchino' , 'peperone' ]

phrases =['oca gallo' , 'hamburger formaggio'  ]

wordphrases = words + phrases

print('\n\nkeywords to search for : ',words)

print('\n\nphrases to search for : ',phrases,'\n\n')


print('\n\nword + phrases to search for : ',wordphrases,'\n\n')

context_d = {}
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(filename)
        file = f.read()
        
        for k in range(len(phrases)):
            if phrases[k] in file:
                print('frase : ',phrases[k], ' in ' , filename)
                newfile  = file.replace(phrases[k], ('\''+phrases[k]+'\''))
                print(newfile)
#        print('\nprinting file :  \n\n'+file)
       # txt = file.lower()
#        print('++++++++hhhhhhhh++++++\n\n',file)
#        txt = file.split()
                txt = shlex.split(newfile)
#        print('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n\n',txt)
                txt = [item.replace('May', '') for item in txt]  # locate and replace all months of May before lowering
       #txt = list([[word.lower() for word in line.split()] for line in txt])
                txt = (list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), txt)))
#        print('\n\n printing txt : \n\n',txt,'\n\n')
            for j in range(len(txt)):
#          if (j + 3) < len(txt):
                if txt[j] in wordphrases:
                    if txt[j] in context_d:
                        context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j - 3):j]
                        context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 4)]
                    else:
                        context_d[txt[j]] = txt[(j - 3):j]
                        context_d[txt[j]] += txt[(j + 1):(j + 4)]


    

for i in context_d:
    context_d[i] = list(set(context_d[i]))
    
for i in context_d:
    print('\nRISULTATO per ',i ,' : ','\n      ', context_d[i],'\n\n')
```

When run I got:

```
keywords to search for :  ['pippo', 'papera', 'asino', 'ciuchino', 'peperone']


phrases to search for :  ['oca gallo', 'hamburger formaggio'] 




word + phrases to search for :  ['pippo', 'papera', 'asino', 'ciuchino', 'peperone', 'oca gallo', 'hamburger formaggio'] 


frase :  oca gallo  in  ./uno.txt
gallina sparviero Mulo tonno  ASINO maiale foca cavallo boa struzzo May May

peperone cipolla aglio cavolo 'oca gallo' bue pippo mucca

frase :  oca gallo  in  ./tre.txt
pinguino leone mummia 'oca gallo' levriero bassotto pecora capra

frase :  hamburger formaggio  in  ./due.txt
pizza pasta tagliolini acciughe peperone burro oca cavolo baccala

pollo pizza pasta gamberi peperone uva cipolla grano

pesce gatto mulo ASINO verdura broccoli pippo 'hamburger formaggio' panna


RISULTATO per  asino  :  
       ['cavallo', 'pesce', 'tonno', 'foca', 'sparviero', 'broccoli', 'maiale', 'verdura', 'mulo', 'gatto', 'pippo'] 



RISULTATO per  peperone  :  
       ['', 'struzzo', 'uva', 'burro', 'grano', 'acciughe', 'pizza', 'cipolla', 'gamberi', 'cavolo', 'tagliolini', 'pasta', 'oca', 'aglio'] 



RISULTATO per  oca gallo  :  
       ['pecora', 'pinguino', 'leone', 'bue', 'mucca', 'mummia', 'cipolla', 'cavolo', 'pippo', 'bassotto', 'levriero', 'aglio'] 



RISULTATO per  pippo  :  
       ['panna', 'hamburger formaggio', 'bue', 'mucca', 'broccoli', 'oca gallo', 'verdura', 'cavolo', 'asino'] 



RISULTATO per  hamburger formaggio  :  
       ['broccoli', 'verdura', 'panna', 'pippo']
```

Is this the right behavior?

This time when a phrase is next to a keyword it is flagged as to be retrieved

but counts as '1' position so you get more than just -3 +3 words next to a

keyword

Let me know if it is right (sure there would be better faster more pythonic ways).